# Error connecting to Web Service in C#

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webservice-client

I am trying to access a web service and calling a method to pass my request parameters. I am programmatically setting my credentials, using:

```
service.Credentials = 
      new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain_url");
```

When in the above code, I pass `domain_url`, I get this Web Exception,

`Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine "ServerUrl" failed. Invalid access to memory location.`

When I do not pass `domain_url`:

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

It does not throw the Web Exception, rather it throws Soap Exception, that only says "Internal Error" with no error code.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "Unable to automatically step into the server" is a debugging error message.

Comment: What error messages can you find in the event log or the IIS logs?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Ashar? If so (and you remember what it was) would you mind posting as an answer below?